# Webdriverio (standalone) - assigning a variable to elements allows me to run webdriver functions.. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

```
    const { remote } = require('webdriverio');
const assert = require('assert');
const MetisAdmin_Workflow = require('../pageObjects/metisAdminPage/MetisAdmin_Workflow');

module.exports = function(){
    // const app = new Application ({
    //     path: 'C:/Metis/Metis.exe'  
    //   });

    var browser;
    describe('admin page test', function () { //mocha doesnt like arrow functions for some reason.
        this.timeout(20000); //this needs to be mocha suite
            

        // this runs once before all tests. 
        before(async () => {
            browser = await remote({ // if the tests grow we will need move this somewhere. 
                capabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' }
            });
        });          

        it('testing', async function(){
            // if these are meant to be combined with metis flows
            // it there needs to be a smart way to combine this with metis tests. 
            // should there be a user created for the purpose of tests. - i dont want to use my own creds/. 
            
            const workflowPage_ = await new MetisAdmin_Workflow(browser); // create instance of pageobjects and pass in the browser object
            await workflowPage_.open();
            let flowButton = await workflowPage_.leftMenu_.flows;
            await flowButton.waitForExist(10000);
            await flowButton.click();
```

So I writing an automation test tool at work and trying to implement pageobject design.

I came across an error that was causing the click() function or anyother built in webdriver functions to "not be a function".

if I call it like this -

```
let flowButton = await workflowPage_.leftMenu_.flows;
    await flowButton.waitForExist(10000);
    await flowButton.click();
```

it works fine although i get an error saying the element assigned to flows is not found and waits for it,

however if i do this -

```
await workflowPage_.leftMenu_.flows.waitForExist(10000)
await workflowPage_.leftMenu_.flows.click();
```

it will crash and say that waitforExist is not a function and click is not a function ... can anyone explain this to me? It might save me headaches and time if I knew how that works.

Answer (score 0):

this is not related to WebdriverIO.

In JavaScript, you have to await Promises one by one.

```
const leftMenu = await workflowPage_.leftMenu_
await leftMenu.flows.waitForExist(10000)
await leftMenu.flows.click();
```